# Filter Django database for field containing any value in an array

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model and a field representing a users full name. My client wants me to set up a filter to search for a user based on an array of strings where all of them have to be case insensitive contained within the full name.

For example

If a users `full_name = "Keith, Thomson  S."`

And I have a list `['keith','s','thomson']`

I want to perform the filter equivalent of

```
Profile.objects.filter(full_name__icontains='keith',full_name__icontains='s',full_name__icontains='thomson')
```

The problem is this list can be of dynamic size - so I do not know how to do this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Make successive calls to `filter`, like so:

```
queryset = Profile.objects.all()
strings = ['keith', 's', 'thompson']
for string in strings:
    queryset = queryset.filter(full_name__icontains=string)
```

Alternatively you can `&` together a bunch of `Q` objects:

```
condition = Q(full_name__icontains=s[0])
for string in strings[1:]:
    condition &= Q(full_name__icontains=string)
queryset = Profile.objects.filter(condition)
```

A more cryptic way of writing this, avoiding the explicit loop:

```
import operator
# ...
condition = reduce(operator.and_, [Q(full_name__icontains=s) for s in strings])
queryset = Profile.objects.filter(condition)
```

Comment: I wonder what the final sql expression is going to look like after chaining all these filters.

Comment: @akonsu I just tried it (well, something similar) -- it gets translated to a series of `AND`s in the `where` clause, i.e. `full_name LIKE %keith% AND full_name LIKE %s% AND ...`

Comment: @isbadawi, +1 - note that the default operator for multiple Q objects is AND so you can just `*[Q1, Q2, Q3]` without using reduce / operator.and_.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi -- does this work on primary keys too. i am having similar issue, obj = ModelClass.objects.filter(name__contains("substr")) name is a primary key ?

Answer (score 13):

Even shorter using the `operator` functions `and_` or `or_` to combine the list of `Q()` conditions

```
from operator import and_, or_
li = ['keith', 's', 'thompson']
```

Items that match all the strings (`and_`)

```
Profile.objects.filter(reduce(and_, [Q(full_name__icontains=q) for q in li]))
```

Items that match any of the strings (`or_`)

```
Profile.objects.filter(reduce(or_, [Q(full_name__icontains=q) for q in li]))
```

The `Q()` function implements `__or__()` and `__and__()` to join two `Q()` objects together, so they can be called using the corresponding `operator` functions.

Comment: First you must import the radius `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 2):

something along these lines:

```
array = ['keith', 's', 'thomson']
regex = '^.*(%s).*$' % '|'.join(array)
Profile.objects.filter(full_name__iregex=regex)
```

EDIT: this is wrong, the OP wants names which contain all strings simultaneously.