# How to check if a string contains any one of the value of a list in a query in Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I need to create a query in which i want to check if the field "Answer_String" contains any one of the value from a list.

I did it in this way:

```
q=queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(answer_string__contains = item) for item in answerList)))
```

There are a no. of checkboxes from which user can select multiple answers and i have created the list.any value in answer_string field can contain multiple answers in the string. but i want to check if the string contains any one of the value from the list it should take it as a yes.

This query i wrote  returns me zero results. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```
queryset.filter(answer_string__in = answerList)
```

Also, I don't think that you should use operator.and_ rather operator.or_

Check Also this link
[Filter Django database for field containing any value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949145/filter-django-database-for-field-containing-any-value-in-an-array/8949234#8949234)

Comment: the answer_string could be like: "This is my answer" and the list would be having just "answer" . this might fail the condition.

Comment: Soory i didnt mention this in the question .i will uodate it right now.

Comment: OK, in this case you did you try using operator.or_

Comment: Yes updating it would help

Comment: Yes i tried and also took the sql query generated from it and run it  and it gave error i.e syntex error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if field contains "any" value of the list use `operator.or_`

`operator.and_` concatenates the smaller Q objects by `and`. So your current query is searching for a field value which contains all the list values.