# django check if word is in model field

Tags: django, django-models

**i searched a lot before posting this question but i didn't find the answer i was looking for**.
i recently added the seach function to my Django powered site this is the code:
my Html input name is 'q' and the form action is:`{% url searcher %}` 
my url: `url(r'^sercher$', views.searcher, name='searcher'),`
the view:

```
def searcher(request):
    Userinput = request.GET.get("q")
    return render(request, 'music/FP.html', {'FP': Project.objects.filter(Userinput)})
```

and it's working,  for example if i have a project_title called "my project" and the user searched for "my" the search function wont work the user have to type "my project" how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Django database for field containing any value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949145/filter-django-database-for-field-containing-any-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

The current way you have your `.filter()` working, an exact match must be typed for a result to be displayed. You may want to try using `icontains` instead like so:

*Note: it is better to keep variable names lowercased.*

*Note 2: replace 'fieldname' with whichever field in your model you want to search.*

```
def searcher(request):
    userinput = request.GET.get("q")
    return render(request, 'music/FP.html', {'FP': Project.objects.filter(fieldname__icontains=userinput)})
```